# MVC/EF - How to add an entity association

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have an Entity in EF called Advertiser and another called Client. Advertisers have a association field called Client, which is selected from a dropdownlist. I want to know how to save this association to the database. The approach I've used is to find the Client object (by using the Id) and then assign this Client object to the Advertiser.Client navigation property. I hoped that by then Adding this Advertiser property, I'd have added an Advertiser that is associated with an existing Entity. However this was not the result. Instead, a new Client record also got added to the table. How do I fix this?

Full explanation and code bits are below...

```
public class Advertiser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

}
```

And another called Client

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        Advertisers = new List<Advertiser>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Advertiser> Advertisers { get; set; }
}
```

A bunch of clients are added to the database in a separate view. When the user lands on the Advertiser views, they have the create option. What I want the create to do is allow the user to pick a client from a drop down list containing all clients. I want this advertiser to then be associated with that client.

This is the code for the controller:

```
//
// POST: /Advertiser/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Advertiser advertiser,int Id)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        advertiser.Client = clientRepo.Retrieve(Id); // Finds and returns a Client object
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saving Advertiser, with int Id = {0} and Client.Id = {1}", Id, advertiser.Client.Id);
        repo.Create(advertiser);
        repo.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(advertiser);
}
```

The Advertiser view populates a dropdownlist with all the Clients and then returns the Id for the currently selected Client.

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @{
            var clients = new Repository<Client>().FetchAll();
            var clientLists = new SelectList(clients, "Id", "Name");
         }
        @Html.DropDownList("Id", clientLists)
    </div>
```

Now, this view correctly returns the correct Id. The Debug.Writeline also confirms that the correct Id is being passed back. The problem lies in what happens after that...

Instead of inserting a new Advertiser that is associated with the existing Client entity, what it does is, it first inserts an Advertiser, and then inserts a copy of the Client entity to the database. This results in duplicate Clients that differ only in primary key (Id),

**I know this can be solved by exposing the foreign key and passing the foreign key instead of finding and referencing the appropriate Client to the the Advertiser.Client property. But if possible I'd prefer to do this without exposing foreign keys. Is there some way this can be done? ... i.e. What am I doing wrong?**

If what goes on in the Repository class could be useful to answer this question, I've added it below:

```
    public OperationStatus Create(TEntity item)
    {
        OperationStatus status = new OperationStatus {Status = true};
        var value = DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(item);

        if(value == null)
        {
            status = null;
        }

        return status;
    }

    public TEntity Retrieve(int id)
    {
        return DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that your repository creates and destroys a `DbContext` with each operation/method.  Can you either confirm that and/or post your repo code?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Key] Attribute to the ID property on both Client and Advertiser